# how to call a form in Enterprise Architect on Elenemt properties window OK button click

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In my addin I'm using `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified()` event to call my form, but each time element properties is modified it is called. So can I get to know when`OK_button` in properties window is clicked so I can call my form.

```
public void EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(EA.Repository Repository, string GUID, EA.ObjectType ot)
{
    // userForm();
}
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no straightforward way to do this.

You can use `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` to set status of "user in item edit window" and then process `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified()` on whether the user has that status or not.

(however, there doesn't seem to be a way to detect if the user clicks cancel, so you have to find a way to reset the status if the user quits the element edit window)

The other solution i can think of is to make your own Element Edit window.